# Looking for advice on using Parceljs with Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, parceljs

I have a number of new and existing projects which use Require.js to manage dependencies.  I am intrigued by the simplicity of Parceljs and would like to test it on a few smaller projects.

I am unsure, however, how to indicate dependencies in my code.  Using a simple require statement like this:

```
// Import our view
var AppView = require('./app.view');
```

would correspond with some examples I have seen.  Is that congruent with the Parcel design philosophy?  It sure is simpler than maintaining Require.js config files but I would prefer to get this right the first time.

My primary concern with using require statements is that it is not a comprehensive approach.  Calling a module via the router, for example, would likely fail as the dependency to the module JavaScript file would be unknown.  An alternative would be to add require statements in the router for every module but that seems to go against the Parcel design philosophy from what I can determine.

Comment: Are you dynamically loading files using requirejs?

Comment: @TJ  Yes, I am currently using requirejs on some projects and webpack on projects I inherited.  I am thinking that Parcel can replace both of those and require less maintenance.

Comment: From a quick look it seems parcel only makes a single bundle? I could be wrong though...

Comment: From the web site:  "Parcel supports zero configuration code splitting out of the box. This allows you to split your application code into separate bundles which can be loaded on demand, which means smaller initial bundle sizes and faster load times. As the user navigates around in your application and modules are required, Parcel automatically takes care of loading child bundles on demand."   So it looks supported but am a little puzzled about the use with Backbone.js.   Maybe I'll try a few tests...

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping for some guidance from the gurus but I realise Backbone.js is a bit passe these days.

I have decided the best course forward for these projects is to use ES2015 modules, Babel for transpiling, and Parcel.  I ran a few tests and it appears that Parcel can replace Browserify for this purpose.